# How do I split each record in a column to new columns using the the key as column namesin Panda

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv")

print(df)

| ID | response | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 234 | {"statusCode":"00","statusDescription":"Successful","mRecord":"202111105530685","tranxReference":"012021116029","recipient":"09131976","amount":"1500","Code":"202505651505637179","network":"MVP","tranxDate":"14-11-2021 10:50 am"} | 2021-11-14 10:50:55 |
| 235 | {"statusCode":"00","statusDescription":"Successful","mRecord":"2021111496980","tranxReference":"01202111057048","recipient":"091598","amount":"1500","confirmCode":"D211114.1050040","network":"MVP","tranxDate":"14-11-2021 10:50 am"} | 2021-11-14 10:50:56 |

I want to split all the records on "response" columns columns in another dataframe and all the keys will for the column header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in two steps: first exploding the records in `response` and then concat with `df` after dropping the original `response` column. You might need to apply `json.loads` since your json record seems to be read as string:

```
import json
df_response = pd.json_normalize(df['response'].apply(json.loads))
df_out = pd.concat([df.drop('response', axis=1), df_response], axis=1)
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
    ID                 Date statusCode statusDescription  ...                Code network            tranxDate      confirmCode
0  234  2021-11-14 10:50:55         00        Successful  ...  202505651505637179     MVP  14-11-2021 10:50 am              NaN
1  235  2021-11-14 10:50:56         00        Successful  ...                 NaN     MVP  14-11-2021 10:50 am  D211114.1050040
```

Comment: After applying this code, I was getting this error 

TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not float

Then I converted the column to string.

Now this error is showing

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: What does `df['response'].dtype` return? Try without `apply(...)` or by first converting `df['response']` to string

Comment: df['response'].dtype
object

Yeah, when I tried without apply i.e.
df_response = pd.json_normalize(all_mrl['response']).

I got this error response: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'


However, after converting it to string

df["response"] = str(df["response"])

Then run
import json
df_response = pd.json_normalize(df['response'].apply(json.loads))

I got this error

JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 10 (char 9)

Comment: `str(df["response"])` isn't correct, you should use `df['response'].astype("string")`

Comment: df['response'].astype("string")

I got the Same error.....

JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 10 (char 9)

Comment: I reloaded the dataset then used this df['response'].astype("string")

I got this error-----JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 11 (char 10)

Comment: can't really help you without anymore details. could you try to edit your question with a bigger part of your data? Showing a small part of your csv that is causing problem.